# Should the following verbs take the singular or plural form?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

The sentence is as follows,

> Multinational corporations carry out various commercial activities
> around the world, such as purchasing raw materials, setting up
> factories, exporting goods, opening branches, listing and financing,
> which promote the global flow of raw materials, talents, commodities,
> and capital, and connect the economies of various regions, which
> become interdependent. At the same time, they also promote cultural
> exchanges.

My questions are

1. Is the sentence okay?
2. Should the words "promote" and "connect" in the above sentence take the singular form (i.e. "promotes" and "connects") or the plural form?

Thank you

Comment: No the sentence is not okay.  It's far too long to take in. By the time you get to the end, you've forgotten how it started.  It tries to say far too much in one breath. To be clear, it either needs to be broken up or to make use of bullet points.

Comment: Yes, the sentence is too long. Is it okay if I change it like this? "Multinational corporations carry out various commercial activities around the world, such as purchasing raw materials, setting up factories, exporting goods, opening branches, and listing and financing. They promote the global flow of raw materials, talents, commodities, and capital, and connect the economies of various regions, which become interdependent. At the same time, they also promote cultural exchange."

Comment: Much improved. Prefer the plural **cultural exchanges**. Inserting **and** after branches and again after **listing** implies that **listing and financing** go together. If they don't, drop the first **and**..

Answer (score 2):

The example seems fine.

The term 'activities' is plural, and that necessitates the use of plural verbs.  'Promote' and 'connect' are right.  The 'they' near the end reminds us of that.

Multinational corporations carry out various commercial 'activities' around the world, such as purchasing raw materials, setting up factories, exporting goods, opening branches, listing and financing, which promote the global flow of raw materials, talents, commodities, and capital, and connect the economies of various regions, which become interdependent. At the same time, 'they' also promote cultural exchanges.